# What is the abbreviation for wm in wm_concat?

Tags: oracle

There are lots of aggregation functions in the Oracle database with the prefix `wm_`, such as `wm_concat`. What does `wm` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workspace Manager, [which still exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adwsm/index.html).

The function used to be under the WMSYS schema. You can see it's removal referred to in [this support document](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2368194_1.html), where an older version was queried (quoting from the public part):

```
select * from SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'EXECUTE' and OWNER = 'WMSYS';
WM_CONCAT_IMPL
WM_CONCAT
WM$GETDBVERSIONSTR
WM$DISALLOWQNDML
WM$CONVERTDBVERSION
OWM_9IP_PKG
```

Of course, it was never officially supported and shouldn't have been used other than by internal Oracle tools, and it not longer exists.